# Angular 9 observable unsubscribe using @ngneat/until-destroy npm package

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular9

I am using `@ngneat/until-destroy` [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngneat/until-destroy/v/7.1.5) npm package to auto unsubscribe observables. I have used `checkProperties: true` to auto unsubscribe observables.

But, I am not getting how to test it. Whether observable is getting unsubscribed or not?

My question is simple. Does this code work or do I have to use pipe like this before subscription

```
.pipe(untilDestroyed(this))
```

Thank you in advance

```
import { UntilDestroy, untilDestroyed } from '@ngneat/until-destroy';

@UntilDestroy({ checkProperties: true })

@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-all-purchase',
  templateUrl: './view-all-purchase.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-all-purchase.component.scss']
})

export class ViewAllPurchaseComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy  {

  
  ngOnInit() {

 this.subscibe1 =  this.vendorService.five_vendors().subscribe(data => {
    if(data){
      console.log(data)
       this.vendor_list = data
    }})

}

ngOnDestroy() {
 
 }
 
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to unsubscribe from the observable? When do you want to unsubscribe from it?

Comment: Actually, I have gone through some articles stating memory leaks due to observables. So it is important to unsubscribe observable when component is destroyed i.e. ngOndestroy() method

Comment: That is true for some observables, mostly custom ones. If you don't unsubscribe those during `ngOnDestroy()`, they'll stay. The ones that make http requests using `HttpClient` do not need to be unsubscribed as they are automatically unsubscribed when the request has finished.

Comment: Okay thanks. Have you used until destroy npm package?  Does checkproperties : true works or I have to use pipe(untildestroyed(this)) .

Comment: @user13258211 please don't perpetuate wrong information, *ALL* observables need to be unsubscribed, even the ones from the HttpClient:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/46542

Answer (score 3):

To check if your observable is unsubscribed, you can add a console.log to your subscription (you already have that but put if outside of the `if(data){}` ) and then change the observable in another component after the ViewAllPurchaseComponent should have been destroyed. If you get a console.log from the ViewAllPurchaseComponent when changing the observable in another component, it was not unsubscribed.

I don't know about the '@ngneat/until-destroy', I usually use

```
ngOnDestroy(){ 
   this.subscibe1.unsubscribe();
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I know this approach, but I am not looking for it. I want to auto unsubscribe observables using above npm package.

Comment: Ok, but now you can check if the observable is unsubscribed with the console.log.

Comment: I'm also looking for the same. They example that they gave in github repo works.

Comment: Even without using the package related to OP's question, unsubscribing manually is prone to mistakes and oversight. You should use rxjs takeUntil https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takeuntil

Comment: @Mozgor `takeUntil` is unnecessary if you use the pipe from this package, that's what it's all about, replacing `takeUntil`, `take(1)`, and other similar pipes.

Comment: That's precisely the point of my comment : should anyone refuse to use until-destroyed for whatever reason, the solution of unsubscribing manually is still to avoid.

I agree that package is imho the best solution, but here we're commenting on a answer which displays an out-of-date alternative.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use *untilDestroyed* this way:

```
this.subscibe1 =  this.vendorService.five_vendors()
**.pipe(untilDestroyed(this))**
.subscribe(data => {
if(data){
  console.log(data)
   this.vendor_list = data
}})
```

Answer (score 1):

I use it like this

```
import { UntilDestroy, untilDestroyed } from '@ngneat/until-destroy';
    
@UntilDestroy()
@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-all-purchase',
  templateUrl: './view-all-purchase.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-all-purchase.component.scss']
})

export class ViewAllPurchaseComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscibe1 = this.vendorService.five_vendors().pipe(
      untilDestroyed(this)
    ).subscribe(data => {
      if (data) {
        console.log(data)
        this.vendor_list = data
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best pattern is to use the async pipe

```
export class ViewAllPurchaseComponent {
  vendor_list$ = this.vendorService.five_vendors();

  constructor(private vendorService: VendorService) {}
}
```

and in the template use

```
<ng-container *ngIf="vendor_list$ | async as vendor_list">
  Vendor list is available here {{ vendor_list | json }}
</ng-container>
```

Comment: This is irrelevant. The user may not want to unsubscribe in the template, in which case the async pipe is useless.